# Migrations: purpose of the startup project

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

When carrying out an `update-database` in the package manager you have to select a project as the startup project and the output from the command tells you what the startup project it is using.  My question is what is the significance of the startup project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start-up project is used to find the correct App/Web.config file and the output directory to use.

Consider the following. You're DbContext exists in ClassLibrary1 which is used by WebApplication1. The settings that EF will ultimately use are stored in the Web.config of the WebApplication1 project. When using migrations commands, you would specify ClassLibrary1 as the default project and WebApplication1 as the start-up project. Also, if you were using relative paths somewhere inside your context or migrations, you would want them to resolve relative to WebApplication1's output directory, not ClassLibrary1's.

Of course, if everything is in one project, you don't have to worry about the start-up project since it will always be the same as the default project.